# I want a button on view page of account which will activate only when all the fields are filled

Tags: apex, visualforce, account

I want a button on view page (which is a Visual force page) of account which will activate only when all the fields are filled.
Kindly help me out for this logic .
is there any other way to achieve this.

**Below is my requirement :-**

Apart from save button i want additional submit button which will only activate when all the fields are filled up.This button is for triggering a workflow!.

Answer (score 1):

You can have 2 page layouts : one with the button and second without the button. Each of the layouts is assigned to different recordType. 
Then You can create a Workflow rule with field update to change the recordType when all fields are populated..

Comment: I am using a visualforce page

Answer (score 0):

As you want the button in standard page, It cannot be activated/enabled. Instead of activating/enabling it we can check for the fields and if they are filled we can allow it to perform the action else throw an error asking to fill the fields.

Answer (score 0):

You can check all field in particular region of page by jquery like this

```
$('#submit-button').click(function() {

    $('input').each(function(){
        if($(this).val() != ''){
            console.log($(this).id +' field is empty ');
            $('#submit-button').attr('disabled',true);// make button disable
        }
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot achieve this by adding a button to the standard page layout, as this button will always be visible and activated. You need to write a Visualforce page. In this page you can customize the view as you want. You may even include the standard page layout with apex:detail tag. Concerning the button, you can use javascript/jquery to activate/deactivate the button depending on your input fields. Or you can simply use the rendered attribute of your apex:commandButton element. But this will only active/deactivate the button on page load, not on real time. Good luck.